# Managing memory properly inside and outside an ISR routine across multiple source files

Tags: c++, memory, volatile, extern, isr

I'm externing a volatile pointer but it seems to collapse my program upon accessing it in memory.
I'm looking for best practices and maybe a solution to what I can do to make it work.

main.cpp:

```
rc_MCP9804 mcp1(0x18);
volatile rc_temperature_sensor *rc_temp1 = &mcp1;
Serial.print(rc_peltier_state.current_temp1_c)
```

main.h:

```
extern volatile rc_temperature_sensor *rc_temp1;
```

other.cpp:

```
void updatePeltierControl(){
    rc_peltier_state.current_temp1_c = rc_temp1->getTemperature();
}
```

If I comment out the ISR routine and just request rc_temp1->getTemperature() in my main loop it works fine. I think there is some memory management issues between the two. All of my original code compiles.

The ISR routine with more specificity is the following:

```
void initPeltier(uint8_t timing_slot_num, uint16_t update_freq_ms) {

    // Attach ISR callback
    attachRcTimingFunc(
        timing_slot_num,
        &updatePeltierControl,
        update_freq_ms,
        1 // Persistent
    );

}
```

Comment: Is `rc_temp1` a global? Will it be set before the ISR is installed?

Comment: rc_temp1 is a global and it is set before IRS.

Comment: I guess we need to see what `getTemperature` does.